# Alert Message in ASP.Net with System.Net.Mail

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, alert, system.net.mail

Here my code

```
  protected void Unnamed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
            mail.To.Add(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailTo"].ToString());
            mail.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailUse"].ToString(), "Contacto_PortalWeb", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            mail.Subject = txtsubject.Text;
            mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            mail.Body = "Nombre: " + txtName.Text + "<br/><br/>Correo: " + txtemail.Text + "<br/><br/>Telefóno: " + txtphone.Text + "<br/><br/>Compañia: " + txtcmpnm.Text + "<br/><br/>Contenido: <br/>" + txtmsg.Text;
            mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
            //SMTP CLIENT
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtp"].ToString());
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailUse"].ToString(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"].ToString());
            client.Port = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"].ToString());
            client.Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtp"].ToString();
            client.EnableSsl = true;

            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Mensaje enviado!');", true);
            CleartextBoxes(this);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Exception ex2 = ex;
            string errorMessage = string.Empty;
            while (ex2 != null)
            {
                errorMessage += ex2.ToString();
                ex2 = ex2.InnerException;
            }
            //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "UserMsg", "<script type='text / javascript'>alert('Not send');if(alert){ window.location='contact.aspx';}</script>", true);

            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Por favor intentalo nuevamente ' "+ex2.ToString()+");", true);
        }
    }
```

I have a curious problem, is about the message, this work when the user sends a message, always arrive on my email, but what I want is to display an alert window type "message sent" when the user gives the submit button but not achievement that shows the alert window ... so how can show this alert ???

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Are you asking "How do I make a javascript alert window in the response?" or are you asking "How do I make a cool looking popup as a notification without using the javascript alert function in the response?" Maybe you are asking something else, but my point is that your question is hard to understand.

Comment: yeah that... i need to show a popup or alert... with or without JS... help !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you have a ScriptManager on you page, this should work...

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "alertMessage","alert('Message sent!)');", true);
```

**Answer to your second question**

Ok, you're not actually calling client.Send() anywhere in your try block. This is why you are always seeing the 'Mensaje enviado!' alert message, when you're expecting it to fail.

Add the following line below `client.EnableSsl = true;`

```
client.Send(mail);
```

If the message is sent without an exception being thrown, you will see the  'Mensaje enviado!' alert message.

If there was an exception, the code in your Catch block will run and should display the 'Por favor intentalo nuevamente' alert message instead.

Comment: Thanks !, but, in the part of the error, what would be the code that can show if the message has not been sent, because I think my code is wrong because when i test it should not send the message... even it show that the message was sent as usual when I must not be so... any idea ???

Comment: Please update the code in your question with what you currently have now and I'll take a look.